# In a database schema, should frequently changed information be isolated from static information?

Tags: database, schema

A contrived example:

I have many Thimbles, identified in real-life by their color, that I lend out to friends. I want to know only the most recent friend that is wearing my Thimble. My friends covet my thimbles, so this information changes frequently.

Options I can think of are:

1. Keep the lending information in the main thimble table
2. Create a new table just for lending

#### Option 1 (1 Table with all info):

owned_thimble

| Thimble ID | Color | Friend | Lent Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Blue | Mary | 2021-7-23 |
| 2 | Green | Paul | 2021-6-13 |

#### Option 2 (2 Tables with constraints)

owned_thimble

| Thimble ID | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | blue |
| 2 | green |

lent_thimble

| Thimble ID | Friend | Lent Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Paul | 2021-6-13 |
| 1 | Mary | 2021-7-23 |

---

When Paul inevitably returns my thimble, I'd want to lend it back out to another friend. When that happens, in Option A I am updating a row partially -- the Thimble ID is always associated with the same Colored thimble --  in Option B all the information related to lending a thimble is replaced.

Is either approach better or worse than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I'd say option A is not normalized because neither friend nor lent time column describe the key (a given thimble identified with and ID).
- Option B is correct and normal.
- I would name the first table just `THIMBLE` and the second table `THIMBLE_LENDING`.
- `THIMBLE_LENDING` actually represents an event (a thimble is lend) and that can be deduced by the fact that one of the columns is a timestamp.
- For this to be completely normalised, I would create a third table `FRIEND` and have `THIMBLE_LENDING` have a FK pointing to it. That would prevent any update anomally.
- Finally you can create a view to put it all back together for easy of use:

```
create view LENT_THIMBLES as
select
   t.thimble_id,
   t.color,
   l.lent_time,
   f.friend_name
from THIMBLE t 
join THIMBLE_LENDING l on (t.thimble_id = l.thimble_id)
join FRIEND f on (l.friend_id = f.friend_id);
```

Normalization is good for performance, avoids update or insert anomalies and makes growth easier like for example the need of keeping an historical record or all `THIMBLE_LENDINGS` wich is harder with the non-normal version.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Performance** I have seen a separation into two tables for *users*. A heavy-load, almost read-only table for fast authentications, and separately a table for updating a single user's properties.
2. **Performance** The same separation also seen to have a second table of *binary blobs*, which may slow queries down.
3. **Normalisation** An other reason for separation is *normalisation*. Not the case for a 1:1 relation.

One table is easier. An artificial join between two 1:1 tables is a form of antioptimization. Do not overengineer, until required.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer. Arre you recommending option 1? Option 2? Neither option?

Comment: The three points are arguments, practical cases, in favor of separate tables. The last sentence states that one table is generally better though. Unclearly answered.